Routing output from GarageBand to my input mic. Is it possible?
With my iPhone 11, iOS 17.5.1, would it be possible to pass the output of GarageBand off as my input mic device? The purpose is for calls.
A similar question was posted here 4 years ago (How can I use the output sound from GarageBand as my 'mic' for Skype or similar?), yet it doesn’t follow my need as I would like to use only my iPhone, or a laptop to set something up, but nothing that is needed always or it would be pointless.
I understand that it might not be possible to split/redirect the input and output like this, however, my bluetooth earbuds (I don't have to use the earbuds when calling) use the default device built-in. Knowledge of/method to use any external app or technology to change the way the iPhone processes the audio would be much appreciated. I found an app called iEavesdrop by Dennis Nederlof (https://apps.apple.com/app/id541418268), which almost achieves my purpose, but I cannot choose the GarageBand output as the input. Thank you.

Blackhole (https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) is similar to what I want, but once again, I don’t know how to use it/it cannot be used for only iOS.
